# How to use URLrewrite for deploying React Web on a Kestrel server in an ASP.Net Core 2 stateless service using Azure Service Fabric

Tags: url-rewriting, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-2.0, kestrel-http-server, service-fabric-stateless

I am attempting to deploy a React web site to Azure Service Fabric. I am using  kestrel in a stateless ASP.Net Core 2 service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore#kestrel-in-a-stateless-service)

The service runs fine and displays the 1st page of my React Web page correctly without using URLRewrite. However when attempting to use URLrewrite as per the sample (https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/url-rewriting/samples/2.x/Program.cs) no web page (including index.html) is being found i.e. I just receive a 404 error.
Using the debug code to render the rewritten URL appears to have the expected URL.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone, turns out there was a simple solution (the best solutions usually are)
Added the following code at the end of:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
       ........

        //handle client side routes
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            await context.Response.SendFileAsync(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "index.html"));
        });
```